# Matching modified filenames

Tags: python

I have two distinct programs that processed the same input files. During the processing, both programs generated files with names  based on their original counterpart. The possible changes, without considering the modified paths and file extensions, would be, in regex terms, as follow:

- Program**1** can append `(_[[:alnum:]]+)*` to the original filenames.
- Program**2** can append `(_[[:alnum:]]+)*` **and** prepend `([[:alnum:]]+_)*` to the original filenames.

Now, given a list of several millions of file paths from Program**2**, I need to match each one of them to an unique file path from Program**1**.

What would be a sensible way to do it?

Here's where I'm stuck:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

##### DATA #####

program1_files = [
    # Around 10 thousand of unique items (parsed from a file).
    'path1/jobxxx/n1_file_001_xxx.tiff',
    'path1/jobxxx/n1_file_002_yyy_xxx.tiff',
    'path1/jobxxx/n2_file_001_yyy.tiff'
]

program2_files = [
    # Around 10 millions of items (parsed from a file),
    # with only around 10 thousand of unique items
    # IMO the items should be directly processed/matched while parsing the file
    'path2/JXX/00001_n1_file_001_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc',
    'path2/JXX/00001_n1_file_001_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc',
    'path2/JXX/00002_n1_file_002_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc',
    'path2/jXX/00003_n2_file_001_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc',
    'path2/JZZ/00101_YYY_n1_file_001_xx_zzz.mrc',
    'path2/JZZ/00102_YYY_n2_file_001_xx_zzz.mrc'
]

################
```

```py
def get_parts(str):
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(str))[0].split('_')

program1_fileparts = dict(zip(program1_files, map(get_parts,program1_files)))

file2_to_file1 = {}

for file2 in program2_files:

    if file2 in file2_to_file1: continue   # skip already processed file2

    file2_parts = get_parts(file2)

    for file1 in program1_files:

        file1_parts = program1_fileparts[file1]

        # here I'm a little lost on what to do
```

Comment: So, out of those sets, which ones are "matches"? That's not clear to me.  You have two matched for "n1_file_001".  Is that what you want?

Comment: a TIFF can match multiple MRC, but an MRC shall only ever match one TIFF. Fortunately, the original filenames are supposed to all have the same fixed format, with varying digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses a prefix tree to quickly match against the program 1 output files:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Any, Optional

##### DATA #####

program1_files = [
    "path1/jobxxx/n1_file_001_xxx.tiff",
    "path1/jobxxx/n1_file_002_yyy_xxx.tiff",
    "path1/jobxxx/n2_file_001_yyy.tiff",
]

program2_files = [
    "path2/JXX/00001_n1_file_001_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc",
    "path2/JXX/00002_n1_file_002_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc",
    "path2/jXX/00003_n2_file_001_XXX_yyy_zz.mrc",
    "path2/JZZ/00101_YYY_n1_file_001_xx_zzz.mrc",
    "path2/JZZ/00102_YYY_n2_file_001_xx_zzz.mrc",
]

################

def get_parts(s: str) -> list[str]:
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(s))[0].split("_")

def build_prefix_tree(files: list[str]) -> dict[str, Any]:
    """Build a prefix tree of file path parts from program 1."""
    # Node = dict[str, Node | tuple[list[str], str]]

    def insert(node: dict[str, Any], parts: list[str], path: str) -> None:
        if parts[0] not in node:
            # create leaf entry
            node[parts[0]] = (parts[1:], path)
            return
        child = node[parts[0]]
        if isinstance(child, tuple):
            # found a collision with an existing leaf: expand it to a full node
            child_parts, child_path = child
            child = {child_parts[0]: (child_parts[1:], child_path)}
            node[parts[0]] = child
        # recurse into next entry
        insert(child, parts[1:], path)

    prefix_tree: dict[str, Any] = {}
    for file in files:
        insert(prefix_tree, get_parts(file), file)
    return prefix_tree

def recursive_match(node: dict[str, Any], parts: list[str]) -> Optional[str]:
    """Lookup a prefix match in `node`."""
    if parts[0] not in node:
        # couldn't match parts
        return None
    child = node[parts[0]]
    if isinstance(child, tuple):
        # found matching file
        return child[1]
    return recursive_match(child, parts[1:])


tree = build_prefix_tree(program1_files)

file1_to_file2: dict[str, list[str]] = defaultdict(list)
file2_to_file1: dict[str, str] = {}
for file2 in program2_files:
    if file2 in file2_to_file1:
        continue  # skip already processed file2

    file2_parts = get_parts(file2)
    for skip_parts in range(len(file2_parts)):
        # first try skipping no parts, then skip 1 part, then 2, and so on
        parts = file2_parts[skip_parts:]
        if (file1 := recursive_match(tree, parts)) is not None:
            file1_to_file2[file1].append(file2)
            file2_to_file1[file2] = file1
            break
    else:
        # reached the end of the loop without breaking
        print(f"Warning: couldn't find match for {file2}")
```

Comment: Thank you!! I had the same idea of trying to match `file2_parts[0:]` `file2_parts[1:]` etc... but doing it for each `file2` against each `file1` seemed inefficient. Building a search tree feels like a great way to tackle the problem! Now I'll have to add a little safeguard against duplicate matches, which shouldn't exist but you never know, the user (or the programs) might have messed up. It's better to stop early, before launching the follow-up time consuming calculations.

Comment: Based on how the tree is built, the only way you can have duplicate matches is if two different files have the same parts. As-is, it should error out when trying to access `child_parts[0]`, but you can explicitly check that `child_parts` is non-empty and give a more helpful error message (you'll even be able to include the colliding file path in `child_path`).

Comment: I implemented a search tree and compared it to a more basic algorithm in `O(N²)` (N being the number of unique paths) and the results are great!! if I substract the 60 sec needed to parse the files, the rest of the processing takes 4 seconds instead of 21 minutes.